# How to build all projects of all solutions in a folder?

Tags: msbuild

How to build all projects of all solutions in a folder?Creating a new solution with all projects is not feasible for me as I have to add all the dependent projects for each project from "Project Dependencies..." or "Project build order" and I have 150 projects in 30 solutions and project build order is to be maintained for me to build successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding my two cents:

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 so I ran "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" (which exists for every respective version of VS afaik).

Then, I navigated to the root directory of all my solutions I needed to build using Debug configuration and, finally, I executed the following command:

```
for /r %x in (*.sln) do devenv %x /build Debug
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a custom msbuild script. Since you want to preserve the project dependencies within each solution, the remaining option is to find and build all solution files in the directory hierarchy.

When you create a file `buildAllSlns.proj` with the following content:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="**\*.sln" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Solution)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=Release" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

It can be run by calling

```
msbuild buildAllSlns.proj
```

Comment: I am getting "skipping target because all output files are up-to-date" message. How to force it to build?

Comment: You can change `Targets="Build"` to `Targets="Rebuild"`

Comment: Changing to "rebuild" also gives same message. Does this content drill down to all subfolders?

Comment: Is it the only message you get or one of many? would be interesting to know which target was skipped. If it is something that also happens when rebuilding the solution itself then its okay. (e.g. `msbuild the.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild`)

Comment: My project file as given below.<Project DefaultTargets="Rebuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="**\*.sln" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Solution)" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=Release" />
  </Target>
</Project>

Comment: The command "msbuild the.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild" throws error "targer rebuild does not exist". If I use build instead of rebuild I get "skipping target ..." error.

Comment: @bill - Try `/t:Clean;Build`